# ASP.NET MVC 4 - ListBoxFor, send selectedValue in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, selectedvalue, html.actionlink, html.listboxfor

I have a list of model. I want to retrieve the listBoxSelectedValue to send it in my actionLink to edit it.

This is my view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(a => a.SelectedApplis, new SelectList(ViewBag.Applis,"ID","Name", Model.SelectedApplis))<br/>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add","Create","Application")<br/>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Application", null, new { listAppId = Model.SelectedApplis})<br/>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete","Application")<br/>
}
```

I created a class "ListBoxApplication" with the List which will contain the selectedValue of the ListBox.

```
public class ListBoxApplication
{
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedApplis { get; set; }

    public ListBoxApplication()
    {
        SelectedApplis = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

I have 2 controllers : Application and Home

In HomeController, I created the model ListBoxApplication which contain the List. In my ViewBag.Applis, i have all my ApplicationModel.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ListBoxApplication listeApplis = new ListBoxApplication();

        ViewBag.Applis = ApplicationModels.GetListApplications();
        return View(listeApplis);
    }
```

In my ApplicationController :

```
    public ActionResult Edit(ListBoxApplication listAppId)
    {
        // I WANT TO RETRIEVE MY listAppId HERE, but it is always 'null'
        return View();
    }
```

So I think my problem is in the actionLink :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Application", null, new { listAppId = Model.SelectedApplis})
```

Me Edit Method is not is the actual controller (Home/Index). I need to send the selectedValue of my ListBox in my actionLink to (Application/Edit).

The listAppId is always 'null'. It doesn't retrieve the value... Is there a mistake in my actionLink ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: From the code you posted it would seem that ApplicationModels.GetListApplications() is returning null.

Comment: I filled my listApplications. They are displayed in my listBox. So GetListApplications() is operating.

Comment: So Edit expects a ListBoxApplication and you are sending an IEnumerable? Is that what I am seeing?

Comment: Sorry, I was testing with an input before and forget to change it in my post... my edit method is expecting a IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that action links will trigger a postback to the server. Try this instead:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete","Application")<br/>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add","Create","Application")<br/>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Detail","Application"))
    {
        @Html.ListBoxFor(a => a.SelectedApplis, new SelectList(ViewBag.Applis)) //not sure what the other params you had here were for, but it should work like this
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="Edit" value = "Edit"/>
        @*added in response to comment*@
        <input type="submit" name="Delete" value = "Delete"/>
        <input type="submit" name="Add" value = "Add"/>
    }
```

If you plan on having all of those buttons post back to the server, you could also use ajax (and javascript) to accomplish this same goal, without needing to write out a form for each individual button. Both ways would work just fine, multiple forms is technically easier though.

```
public ActionResult Detail(ListBoxApplication listAppId, bool Edit, bool Add, bool Delete)
{
    if(//check your bools here){
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right, we can't have multiple action links in one Form... But you're telling about multiple forms. How can I have 3 forms for each actionlink with just one listbox ? The listBox would only be in one form no ? Or is there another way ?

Comment: ok, so there are a couple ways to do it, one way is to make all of you action links into submit buttons (see code above) and change the value to the text you want displayed. Now each of those when clicked (assuming they are in the form, will submit to the server), now if you give each of them a name, and add that name as a param to your controller, as a string or a bool, then you will be able to figure out which button was clicked. (give me a minute ill mock up a controller in my response)